# How can I can upload the same file multiple times in my protractor test when my application validates for the unique file name on upload?

Tags: selenium, upload, protractor, automated-tests, e2e-testing

In my protractor test, I want to upload the same file to my application in different different occasions, but the application is validating for the unique file name on upload. I need to rename the same file before I upload so that my application will accept it on upload

Comment: just rename the file between uploads?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the code to rename the file in your script, and also make sure you append the **Timestamp** to the file name, so that the file name is unique everytime.